# GWT Deferred Binding for loading only required classes in catch

Tags: gwt, binding, deferred

We have product, whose front end is in GWT. As it contains many classes (Around 150 menus, you can imagine now)

When user access this first time, it takes time to load. (If bandwidth is low then this increases)

Next time onwards it remains in catch, we don't have to worry about bandwidth.

Can I reduce this first time loading time by using GWT deferred binding ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, initial load time can usually be reduced by a lot. You probably want to look into [Code Splitting](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html).

You'll have to make a decision, which parts you need initially, and which parts can be loaded later (and when). Then make absolutely sure, that you don't accidentally use those later parts from your initial code fragment - except from inside `GWT.runAsync`.